# Undefined array key "quantity" in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\cart-item.php

Tags: php

I was following a tutorial video and it doesn't output the table from database. I followed every step on the video. I also tried initialize quantity as variable and it still doesnt work

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "login_sample_db");
    if(isset($_POST['add_to_cart'])){
        if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
            $session_array_id = array_column($_SESSION['cart'], "id");

            if(!in_array($_GET['id'], $session_array_id)){
                $session_array = array(
                    'id' => $_GET['id'],
                    "name" => $_POST['name'],
                    "price" => $_POST['price'],
                    "quantity" => $_POST['quantity']
                );
                $_SESSION['cart'][] = $session_array;
            }

        }else{
            $session_array = array(
                'id' => $_GET['id'],
                "name" => $_POST['name'],
                "price" => $_POST['price'],
                "quantity" => $_POST['quantity']
            );
            $_SESSION['cart'][] = $session_array;
        }
    }
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Products</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cart-item.css">
    <style>
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h2 class="text-center">Shopping Cart Data</h2>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <?php
                                $query = "SELECT * FROM cart_item";
                                $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <form method="post" action="cart-item.php?id=<?= $row['id'] ?>">
                                            <h5 class="text-center"><?= $row['name']; ?></h5>
                                            <h5 class="text-center">$<?= number_format($row['price'], 2); ?></h5>
                                            <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?= $row['name'] ?>">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?= $row['price'] ?>">
                                            <input type="number" name="quantity" value="1" class="form-control">
                                            <input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" class="btn btn-warning btn-block my-2" value="Add To Cart">
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php
                                }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h2 class="text-center">Item Selected</h2>
                    <?php
                        $total = 0;
                        $output = "";
                        $output .= "
                            <table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>Item Name</th>
                                    <th>Item Price</th>
                                    <th>Item Quantity</th>
                                    <th>Total Price</th>
                                    <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                        ";

                        if(!empty($_SESSION['cart'])){
                            foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value){
                                $output .= "
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>".$value['id']."</td>
                                        <td>".$value['name']."</td>
                                        <td>".$value['price']."</td>
                                        <td>".$value['quantity']."</td>
                                        <td>$".number_format($value['price'] * $value['quantity'/*,2*/])."</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href='cart-item.php?action=remove&id=".$value['id']."'>
                                                <button class='btn btn-danger btn-block'>Remove</button>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                ";
                                $total = $total + $value['quantity'] * $value['price'];
                            }
                            $output .= "
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan='3'></td>
                                    <td></b>Total Price</b></td>
                                    <td>".number_format($total, 2)."</td>
                                    <td>
                                    <a href='cart-item.php?action=clearall'>
                                    <button class='btn btn-warning btn-block'>Clear</button>
                                    </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            ";
                        }
                        echo $output;
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

i checked the quantity array key multiple times and compare with videos and it's the same from the video. Is there anything else i shoult try, the table in database also didnt have quantity in it

Comment: you shouldn't get the price from the form. The user can easily modify it in Developer Tools.

Comment: Which line is the error happening on?

Comment: FYI: `a` and `button` are both interactive elements, and as such not allowed to be nested into each other.

Answer (score -1):

Would comment if I could, but without knowing more specifics... are you sure your database schema and tables are defined correctly? What/where is your `INSERT`/`UPDATE` logic? Where is the error happening, exactly? More information please.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).